# add a custom library?

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I am a robotics hobbyist and just started with ROS. I have a custom library (lets call it customLibrary-1.0) that I would like to integrate in my first ROS node. It is my first time using cmake (I am used to autotools) so I am a bit lost with it.

Usually to compile a program that uses the custom library I would do something like:

```
g++ -o myprogram myprogram.cpp `pkg-config customLibrary-1.0 --cflags --libs`
```

The only special thing about customLibrary-1.0 is that it depends on otherCustomLibrary-3.0, but pkg-config takes care of that for me. The result of the pkg-config command would be something like:

```
-I/usr/local/include/customLibrary-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/otherCustomLibrary-3.0 -L/usr/local/lib -lcustomLibrary-1.0 -lotherCustomLibrary-3.0
```

How can I add that library into cmake? I have been reading other posts and surfed the web, but I am confused. Some people suggest using the macros: include_directories() and target_link_libraries(). In other places I read that I should write a file named findCustomLibrary-1.0.cmake full with a lot of macros. How do grown-ups do it? :D

Thanks in advance and sorry for the newbie question.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10875/add-a-custom-library?/) by [flamenco](https://answers.ros.org/users/944/flamenco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2011-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CMake supports finding libraries, see [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#module:FindPkgConfig).
Once you have applied the check... macros you use the variables in include_directories/target_link_libraries, e.g.

`include_directories(${customLibary_INCLUDE_DIRS})`

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flamenco](https://answers.ros.org/users/944/flamenco/) on 2011-08-11**:
Awesome! I had skimmed-trough cmake documentation but didn't pay attention to FindPkgConfig :S